# Cant figure out why php update script is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php page that is supposed to update a record in a database. But for some weird reason, its not updating and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Maybe another pair of eyes can see what I'm missing.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $refnum = $_POST['refnum'];
    $paymentstatus = "Paid";
}

if ((isset($_POST["form_update"])) && ($_POST["form_update"] == "paymentconfirm")) {

    $stmt = $connQlife->prepare("UPDATE cimbooking SET paymentstatus=? WHERE bookingrefnum=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $paymentstatus, $refnum);
    $results = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if($results){
        $updateGoTo = "confirm"; 
        $errorGoTo = "error";
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
            $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        header("Location: ". $updateGoTo);
    }else{
            header("Location: ". $errorGoTo);
    }
}
```

I just get redirected to the confirmation page that says it was successful. But it's not updating the table.

Comment: Add `mysqli_error($connQlife)` to the query in a conditional statement, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Noting. No error! But still not updating.

Comment: @DharmanTrying to understand what was posted.But im not getting that error. The thing is, i'm not getting any error at all. but still not updating record in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've been able to find a fix. The page when it loads first gets the value of **refnum** from the previous submitted page and stores it in the variable `$refnum`.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $refnum = $_POST['refnum'];
    $paymentstatus = "Paid";
}
```

Now this current page has another form for updating the record in the database and is supposed to use the value of the `$refnum` and it submits to itself.

```
if ((isset($_POST["form_update"])) && ($_POST["form_update"] == "paymentconfirm")) {

$stmt = $connQlife->prepare("UPDATE cimbooking SET paymentstatus=? WHERE bookingrefnum=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $paymentstatus, $refnum);
$results = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

if($results){
    $updateGoTo = "confirm"; 
    $errorGoTo = "error";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    header("Location: ". $updateGoTo);
}else{
        header("Location: ". $errorGoTo);
}
}
```

What was happening is that, because it was submitting to itself, the value of the `$refnum` was being lost.

So my fix **(probably not the best way)** was to create a session variable with the value of the `$refnum`so that when the page submitted to itself, i could then retrieve the value of the `$refnum` from the session and use it to update the record.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $refnum = $_POST['refnum'];    
    $_SESSION['REFNUM'] = $refnum;
}

if ((isset($_POST["form_update"])) && ($_POST["form_update"] == "paymentconfirm")) {

        $paymentstatus = "Paid";
        $newrefnum = $_SESSION['REFNUM'];

        $query = ("UPDATE cimbooking SET paymentstatus=? WHERE bookingrefnum=?");
        $stmt = $connQlife->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $paymentstatus, $newrefnum);
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        unset($_SESSION['REFNUM']);

        if($results){
            $updateGoTo = "confirm"; 
            $errorGoTo = "error";
            if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
                $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
            header("Location: ". $updateGoTo);
        }else{
                header("Location: ". $errorGoTo);
        }
    }
```

That worked for me. If anyone has a better way, please do provide. Someone else might just have this same problem and could benefit from our solutions.